# Revealing a hidden div after clicking video element

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to implement a function, that after clicking on video element hidden div would be revealed. I run this function onclick:

```
function vid1(){
document.getElementById("vid1_a").style.display = "block";
}
```

My video element looks like this

```
<video width="250" height="240" controls onclick="vid1()">
      <source src="css/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

And it works, but only if I click on the video itself, doesnt work, when one clicks on the control panel of the video, which can be counterintuitive for a user.
Tried putting video into seperate div to fix the problem, but it's the same, only clicking the video itself reveals the div.

Any other ideas I could try?

Edit:
Thought I would just disable controls, but then there is no way to start the video.

Comment: How are you binding the click handler to the video?

Comment: <video id="vid1" width="250" height="240" controls onclick="vid1()">
     <source src="css/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>